# How can I test MySql createConnection response using jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, mysql2

I just started unit testing and now I find myself in the position where I wish to test if the connection was created successfully or if the response of the function is successful.
(I am aware that this part is debatable in which is it e2e or unit but I still wish to carry out this test)

The following is my current test:

```
test("Create connection", async ()=>{

  const connectionOptions = {

    host:process.env.Database_host,
    user:process.env.Database_User,
    password:process.env.Database_Password,
    database:process.env.database_Name

  }
  const connection = await mysql.createConnection(connectionOptions);

  
  
})
```

Questions:

- How should I proceed from here ?
- Should I create this test in another way?
- If I was not using jest, how can I verify that the response of the function was successful?

Notes: I'm using TypeScript

Comment: You should not test third-party libraries, you can instead mock your mysql client

Comment: @Fcmam5  I read that if I have a thin implementation there was no point in testing a function that is just a wrapper for the third-party libraries as it will mainly just pass the result

Comment: If you really want to test your db connection, it would be an e2e test or an integration test. Here a good blog https://dev.to/walrusai/testing-database-interactions-with-jest-519n